# Convert json object to entity/joda date

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have entitity:

```
@Entity
@Table
   public class product implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7166167496114624228L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
@NotEmpty
@Size(max=300)
private String name;
private String description;
@Size(max=200)
private String text_small;
@Size(max=200)
@NotEmpty
private String url;
@Column
@Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime dateStart = new DateTime();
@Column
@Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime dateEnd = null;
private boolean delete =    false;
private boolean status              =   false;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
private Shop shop;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_type")
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
private TypProduct typProduct;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="category", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<CategoryProduct> category = new HashSet<CategoryProduct>();
 ...settert and getters
```

My controller receive data:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> saveAjax(
        @Valid @RequestBody Product product, BindingResult result) {
    ......
    }
```

And i want to edit this entity via ajax/json, i use jackson 
I have a problem about convert dateStart, dateEnd, shop, typProduct and category.
Standart CustomEditor in @InitBinder not work for this.
How to use MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter, anyone have a example solution?

thx.

Comment: Could u show some exception message when you execute the code?

Answer (score 0):

I have example....

My ajax using jquery

```
function postIt(){
            $.ajax({
              url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/test",             
              data:JSON.stringify({id:1, name:"a normal json object face"}),
              type: 'POST', 
              dataType: 'json', 
              contentType: 'application/json',
              mimeType: 'application/json'
            }).done(function() {
              $( this ).addClass( "done" );
            });
        }
```

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public @ResponseBody String test(@RequestBody final String face){
    System.out.println(face);
    return new Gson().toJson(face);
}
```

The jackson dependencies has been downloaded to my lib.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Don't think this example is an answer fully to your question.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply, I solved the problem myself, if anyone needed a solution

i add to set method in my model:

```
 @JsonDeserialize(using = DeserializerJodaDateTime.class)
```

And DeserializerJodaDateTime.class look like:

```
public class DeserializerJodaDateTime extends JsonDeserializer<DateTime> {

@Override
public DateTime deserialize(JsonParser json, DeserializationContext arg1)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
      DateTimeFormatter formatDaty = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    if (json.getText().isEmpty())
        return null;
    return formatDaty.parseDateTime(json.getText());
}

 }
```

And if i want to use service/dao to get deserialize entity(example for relationship)

```
public class DeserializeShop extends JsonDeserializer<Shop> {

@Autowired
ShopService shopService;

public DeserializerShop() {
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
}

@Override
public Shop deserialize(JsonParser json, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    return shopService.getShop(Integer.parseInt(json
            .getText()));
}

}
```